# dini: how to return key, but not key value?

Tags: config, d

I need return list of keys, but next code return me only keys values.

```
string confpath = buildPath(getcwd, "config.ini");
if (!exists(confpath))  throw new Exception("ERROR: config.ini do not exists");
auto config = Ini.Parse(confpath);

foreach (key; config.keys())    
{
    writeln(key);
}
```

config.ini:

```
images = C:\images
photos = D:\photos
pictures = E:\stuff\pictures
```

Expected output:

```
images
photos
pictures
```

code output:

```
C:\images
D:\photos
E:\stuff\pictures
```

I looked at [sources](https://github.com/robik/DIni), but do not found where I can return only keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use my ini wrapper you can return the keys by .keys from IniSection. IMO "dini" is not that good and offers a "non-userfriendly" inifile wrapper. Besides it doesn't follow SafeD which IMO an ini wrapper definitely should as you shouldn't need pointers for parsing a text-format.

Ex.

```
auto keys = ini.getSection("Root").keys;
```

Or .values for the values.

You can get it here:
https://github.com/BaussProjects/baussini/

Answer (score 2):

In dini, the keys property returns the _keys associative array, which is a 
string[string].

So your foreach should be:

```
foreach (key, value; config.keys())    
{   
    writeln(key);
}
```

Alternatively, you can call the associative arrays keys property to get just the keys.

Edit:
IMO, the naming here is a little confusing. I'd personally call dini's keys function "asMap" or something like this, making it obvious that your getting back a mapping of keys=values.

Comment: Could you remind my how I can get access to, for example, second element in associative array without foreach loop

Comment: On my phone now so this is untested, but you can do config.keys().keys[1]. This will give you access to the key at index 1.